# Is there a list of all the magazines including pictures of them?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm trying to figure out which magazines I'm missing. They have different covers so they are obviously able to be identified separately. I want to know if there is a list that shows a picture or description of which magazines can be found where. This way I can compare that list to what I have already.

The wiki pages only have text descriptions of the locations, not the magazines themselves. Which means I have to rely on memory or guess and check work which would take longer than I'd like.

Comment: Your answer and the other makes this look like a resource request question, which we don't really handle well here.  Rather than asking for the solution (a site that has all the pictures of the magazines), tell us what the root issue is.  Focus on that.

Answer (score 2):

[This guide](http://www.ign.com/wikis/fallout-4/Books_and_Magazines) lists them all by subtitles, so you can differentiate between each edition.

**Astoundingly Awesome Tales**

- *A Gorilla Ate My Patrol Car*: Old north church - Railroad HQ
- *Attack of the Fishmen*: Skylanes Flight 1981
- *Attack of the Metal Men*: Dunwich Borers
- *Curse of the burned*: Crater of Atom
- *Giant Insects Invade*: Sentinel Site
- *Have Dog, Will Travel*: The Institute
- *Invasion of the Zetans*: Hubris Comics
- *My Brain and I*: Boston Mayoral Shelter
- *Rise of the Mutants*: Trinity Plaza
- *Rise of the Radiated*: East Boston Preparatory School
- *Sinister Seafood Strikes*: Outpost Zimonja
- *The Mad Russian's Revenge*: Pickman Gallery
- *The Man Who Could Stop Time*: Park Street Station - Vault 114
- *The Starlet Sniper*: Coast Guard Pier

**Grognak the Barbarian**

- *Blood on the Harp*: Wicked Shipping Fleet Lockup
- *Cometh the Trickster*: Andrew Street Station
- *Demon Slaves, Demon Sands*: Vault 75
- *Demon Slaves, Demon Sands* - Alternate Issue: Vault 81
- *Enter Maula: War Maiden of Mars*: Boston Common
- *Fatherless Cur*: Mass Pike Exchange
- *In the Bosom of the Corsair Queen*: Corvega Assembly Plant
- *In the Lair of the Virgin Eaters*: Hyde Park
- *Jungle of the Bat Babies*: Sanctuary
- *Lost in the Snows of Lust*: Back Street Apparel
- *What Sorcery is This?*: Museum of Witchcraft

**Guns and Bullets**

- *Bear Proofing Your Campsite*: Cambridge Police Station
- *Guide to Hunting Commies*: Ticonderoga
- *Lasers and Hunting, Acceptable Overkill*: Fort Hagen
- *Little Guns for Little Ladies*: Fraternal Post 115
- *Plasma, the Weapons of Tomorrow*: The Castle
- *Street Guns of Detroit*: Gunners Plaza
- *Take Aim, Army Style*: S. Boston Military Checkpoint
- *The Future of Hunting?*: BADTFL Regional Office
- *The Moon: A Communist Doomsday Device!?*: Quincy Ruins
- *Void Those Pesky Gun Laws*: Rook Family House

**Hot Rodder**

- *Flame Job*: Robotics Disposal Ground
- *Hot Pink*: Milton General Hospital - West Roxbury Parking Garage
- *Shark Paint Scheme*: Atom Cats Garage

**La Coiffe**

- *Megaton Hair*: Fallon's Department Store
- *The Hornet's Nest*: Bunker Hill - Charleston Laundry

**Live and Love**

- *Advice From Married Men*: Goodneighbor - The Third Rail
- *An Experience to Remember*: Goodneighbor - Hotel Rexford
- *Beware the Man Handler*: Bunker Hill
- *I Married a Robot*: Diamond City Market - Schoolhouse
- *Life Long Best Friends*: Faneuil Hall
- *Nuke the Man*: College Square
- *Talk Yourself Sober*: Revere Beach Station
- *The Secretary Charmer*: Fiddler's Green Trailer Estates
- *Trim the Fat*: WRVR Broadcast Station

**Massachusetts Surgical Journal**

- *Better Living Through Chems*: Cabot House
- *Cryo-Technology: Haven or Tomb*: Greater Mass Blood Clinic
- *ER Nurses Confess All*: Medford Memorial Hospital
- *Find Your Funny Bone*: Boston Public Library
- *Happy Sedation Special*: Sandy Coves Convalescent Home
- *Let's Play Doctor*: Parsons State Insane Asylum
- *Pay Now, Get Better Later*: Greentech Genetics
- *Raised by Robots*: Med-Tek Research
- *Scars are Cool*: Cambridge Polymer Labs

**Picket Fences**

- *Essential Upgrades*: Saugus Ironworks
- *Modern Hearth*: Hardware Town
- *Modern Lawn Care*: Combat Zone
- *The Home of Tomorrow, Today*: Beantown Brewery
- *Welcome Home*: Weston Water Treatment Plant

**Robco Fun**

- *Atomic Command*: Museum of History
- *Grognak and the Ruby Ruins*: Goodneighbor - Memory Den
- *Pipfall*: Fort Hagen - Command Center
- *Red Menace*: Vault 111 (Holotape only)
- *Zeta Invaders*: Diamond City Market - Valentine Detective Agency

**Tales of a Junktown Jerky Vendor**

- *Benefits of Child Labor*: Longneck Lukowski's Cannery
- *Capitalism and You*: Four Leaf Fishpacking Plant
- *How to Run a Successful Vendor Stand*: Big John's Salvage
- *Suit Up and Succeed*: Wreck of the FMS Northern Star
- *Take Your Business on the Road*: Mystic Pines
- *The Art of Haggling*: Super Duper Mart
- *The Joy of Wealth*: Gwinett Brewery
- *Why I Sold My Mother*: Walden Pond

**Tesla Science**

- *Blast Off to Adventure!*: Mahkra Fishpacking
- *Future of Warfare?*: Reeb Marina
- *Geckos and Gamma Radiation*: University Point
- *Giant Super Weapons*: Mass Fusion Building
- *Rocket Science for Toddlers*: Rocky Cave - Virgil's Laboratory
- *U.S. Army Goes to Space*: HalluciGen Inc.
- *What is Plasma Anyway?*: General Atomics Factory
- *Will Robots Rule the World?*: Arcjet Systems
- *10 Number 1 Hits*: Poseidon Energy

**Taboo Tattoos**

- *Bad Luck Horseshoe*: Vault 81
- *Eagle's Nest*: Thicket Excavations
- *Lucky Clover*: Mass Pike Tunnel West/East
- *Nautical Anchor*: Concord - Civic Access
- *Skulls are Hip*: Irish Pride Industries Shipyard

**Total Hack**

- *Control Robots*: Waltz Consumer Electronics
- *Control Spotlights*: The Shamrock Taphouse
- *Control Turrets*: Wildwood Cemetery

**Tumblers Today**

- *Bobby Picks - More Effective Than Lockpicks?*: Easy City Downs
- *Confessions of a Housebreaker*: Fens Street Sewers
- *Locksmith Certification Special*: Malden Center
- *Mysteries of the Master Key Exposed!*: Poseidon Energy Turbines #18-F
- *Open Any Lock in 5 Seconds Flat*: West Roxbury Station

**U.S. Covert Operations Manual**

- *Bushes, Boxes, and Beehives Camouflage Special*: Libertalia
- *Facepaint Fundamentals*: Federal Ration Stockpile
- *Getting the Drop on Communists*: National Guard Training Yard
- *Look Better in Black*: Revere Satellite Array
- *Not the Soldiers You're Looking For*: Abandoned Shack
- *Squeaky Floorboard, Sudden Death*: Fort Hagen - Command Center
- *Tiptoe Through the Tulips*: USAF Satellite Station Olivia
- *Urban Camoflage*: U.S.S. Constitution
- *Whistling in the Dark*: Lexington - The Switchboard
- *Who Goes There?*: Fort Strong

**Unstoppables**

- *Commie-Kazi vs Manta Man*: Westing Estate
- *Dr. Brainwash and His Army of De-Capitalists*: Shaw High School
- *Trapped in the Dimension of the Sterror-dactyls*: Suffolk County Charter School
- *Visit the Ux-Ron Galaxy*: Hubris Comics
- *Who Can Stop the Unstoppable Grog-na-rok?*: D.B. Technical High School

**Wasteland Survival Guide**

- *Commonwealth Coupon Spectacular*: Nahant Oceanological Society
- *Farming the Wastes*: Wreck of the USS Riptide
- *Guide to Diamond City* - Gorski Cabin
- *Hunting in the Wastes*: Sunshine Tidings Co-op
- *Insect Repellent Special*: Crater House
- *Self-Defense Secrets*: Ranger Cabin
- *The Bright Side of Radiation*: Egret Tours Marina
- *The Scrapyard Home Decoration Group*: Lynn Woods
- *Water Aerobics for Ghouls*: Old Gullet Sinkhole

Comment: @CamelCase Given the context of the question, I think this is an appropriate answer. Or we should just close the question. Otherwise, a proper answer will be ridiculously long for this site as there's several dozens of magazines to cover.

Comment: @Iszi - Looking at the link, yes there are a lot of magazines.  Maybe the OP is asking for too much (asking for pictures for each of these items).  The problem with this answer is if that link goes down, the answer is useless.  Additionally, the OP said they wanted a visual clue, that list tells the OP what they already know (where they can be found).

Comment: @CamelCase I'm the asker and answerer in this case. If you think it would be more benficial to list out all 123 books I could do that.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill - perhaps the question should be along the lines of "How can I efficiently work out where the remaining magazines can be found?" - saying you have some, and cannot find a site that shows the visuals against where they are found...

Comment: @VanBuzzKill - continued... As for the answer, perhaps you could list the books, their location, perks and perhaps the sub-titles that appear on the visuals (I used the link the other answer that contains the visuals, and can see that most, if not all, contain some additional text on the magazines).  I think that would be an improvement.  A list of 123 is better than a dead link?

Comment: This answer also offers an alternative method rather than answering the original request.

Answer (score -1):

Covers of all magazines here: http://plank-69.deviantart.com/gallery/56268613/Bethesda-Games

This site also tells you the location of all the magazines:http://www.usgamer.net/articles/fallout-4-all-magazine-locations-and-types

Comment: Before you start filling this answer with images, it may be more efficient to just post the magazines' titles, like `Grognak: Cometh the Trickster` or `Tumblers Today: Bobby Pins - More Effective Than Lockpicks?` Every magazine has its own subtitle, so that should be enough to make them uniquely identifiable.

Comment: +1, as poor as link-only answers may be, there's not much here to summarize beyond just copying the list.

Comment: The walkthrough would at least be helpful for finding ones such as astoundingly awesome tales, since those give all different perks instead of a stacking perk such as guns & bullets.

Comment: @DCShannon If an answer is link only, and that is the only way to answer the question, then the question needs a good hard look.  Generally, that means the question itself is problematic and needs closing.  Don't upvote answers that only consist of a link.